# C# wpf FTP error

Tags: c#, ftp

i have an error in the code -- the remoteserver  give an error not logged in --

how can i login in ftp with username and password in this code !

Thanks!

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT thumbnail FROM immobilie WHERE immobilieID = " + userVal, conn);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string pics = "ftp://hostname/pics/";

        List<String> pic = new List<String>();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            pic.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
        }
        img_immo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pics + pic));
```

the new uri is correct in it is the right url only problem is the ftp login

Comment: ftp :// username : password @ hostname/ (with no spaces)

Comment: thanks you works perfect!

Comment: Ok, then I put this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use uri with credentials:

```
ftp://username:password@hostname/
```